# How do you pass and recive an output parameter from vb.net to a mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters, output

```
    Dim Def_Command_MySQL1 As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

    Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters.Clear()
    Def_Command_MySQL1.CommandText = "SET @OutID = 10;"
    or
    Def_Command_MySQL1.CommandText = "UPDATE ID_Max1 SET IdMax = IdMax + 1 , @OutID = IdMax + 1 where TypeID>1"
    Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OutID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 41
    Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters("@OutID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Def_Command_MySQL1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    IDMax_Update = Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters("@OutID").Value
```

> Err.Description   "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near **'41 = 10' at line 1" String**

or

> Error = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **'1=IdMax + 1 where TypeID>1' at line 1**

Comment: Not much point going to all that effort adding parameters if you `Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters.Clear()` before you run the query! (not that you actually run the query, which is another slight problem)

Comment: Soo... how did you manage to get a mysql error message when this code doesn't actually execute anything in mysql? I suggest posting the full actual code that reproduces the error

Answer (score 0):

First you set AllowUserVariables on True(Default is False in your connection string see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-6-10-connection-options.html

second get rid of the parameter code, because you replace mysql user defined variables @OutID  with an **actual  value**, which results in your error message.

With

```
SET @OutID = 10;"
```

You set in mysql a user defined variable @OutID to the numer 10.

But in general, following code add two parameters to a insert query

```
 Def_Command_MySQL1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn1, myColumn2) VALUES (@C1, @C2)"
 Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", 1)
 Def_Command_MySQL1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", 2)
 Def_Command_MySQL1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Hi , AllowUserVariables=true  .But it still didn't work out. @OutID is a variable. But the server will set the value and give the same error         right syntax to use near '41=IdMax where TypeID>1' at line 1

Comment: Look show you actual code complete, you still try to add a value to '@OutID'